# filter an array of objects based on key/value and remove it from array

Tags: javascript

In the following function I push and object to the `accountsToDelete` array, I need to then remove the matching object from the `accountsToAdd` array. I am guessing I would have to use a combination of IndexOf, Filter, Reduce but I am still a little rough in understanding how to accomplish this. This is the current function:

```
accountDelete(id, name) {
    const accountsToAdd = this.userForm.value.accountsToAdd;
    const accountsToDelete = this.userForm.value.accountsToDelete;
    this.userForm.value.accountsToDelete.push(
        {
            id: id,
            name: name
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: `accountsToAdd = accountsToAdd.filter(e => e.id !== id);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: @ben it may be a duplicate, but I am glad I asked it as @baao solution is a simple one line of code and I was specifically asking how to accomplish this using the `filter()` method.

Comment: @SandraWillford the approved answer of the duplicate I provided is using `filter`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. By this you can say, that in the `accountToAdd` all entries should be filtered, which `id` fits the to deleted account.

An example:

```
// Initialize both lists.
let accountsToAdd = []
let accountsToDelete = []

// Preparation by adding a account to the first list.
const account = { id: 1, name: 'Max' }
accountsToAdd.push(account)

// Mark account to be removed.
accountsToDelete.push(account)
accountsToAdd = accountsToAdd.filter(acc => acc.id !== account.id)

// Verify result.
console.log(accountsToAdd)
console.log(accountsToDelete)
```

**Note:**
Your both lists are defined as constant. By this you can't use the reassignment.

Comment: thanks, ben's comment was pretty much the same approach and so this works like a charm!

Comment: @SandraWillford yeah, haven't seen the comment, as I wrote this example for u.